# What's Wrong With My Calculation of $E[X]$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Please read my comments, **all answers are wrong** (I have showed contradiction)

**Can someone respond to my comments under Graham Kemp's Answer? I think he made a mistake...**

Let's look at the following problem:

> We choose a point $Y$ on pencil of length 1, S.T $Y\sim
>  \operatorname{Uni}(0,1)$
>
> We break the pencil at that point, choose one of the 2 parts in equal
> probability (1/2), S.T $X$ is the length of the part we chose. ie the
> length of the other part is $1-X$.
>
> 1. Calculate $\mathrm E(X)$.
> 2. Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

For (1) I found that:

The probability for $Y=X$ is $1/2$ while the probability for $Y=1-X$ is also $1/2$. So, the probability for $X=Y$ is $1/2$ while the probability for $X=1-Y$ is also $1/2$.

ie: $E[X]=X*P(X)=1/2 * Y + 1/2 * (1-Y) = 1/2$

But where am I supposed to use the given fact that: $Y\sim \operatorname{Uni}(0,1)$ I don't seem to use this anywhere which indicated I did something wrong.

For (2) I know, $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathrm E(X^2)-\mathrm E(X)^2$ But How to Continue from here?

Comment: Since it is a continuous probability distribution, you will need to use the formulae for E(X) and Var(X) defined using integrals. Your value for E(X) is correct though.

Comment: Every answer here is correct. Perhaps the following comment will help. I claim that $X$ has distribution $\mathcal U[0,1]$. Observe that either $X=Y$ or $X=1-Y$, each with probability $1/2$ (based on which stick you choose). So by the law of total probability \begin{align*}\mathbb P(X\leq t)&=\mathbb P(X\leq t\mid X=Y)\cdot\mathbb P(X=Y)+\mathbb P(X\leq t\mid X=1-Y)\cdot\mathbb P(X=1-Y)\\&=\frac{1}{2}[\mathbb P(Y\leq t)+\mathbb P(1-Y\leq t)]\\&=t,\end{align*} where in the last step we use $Y\sim\mathcal U[0,1]$. So $X$ has the claimed distribution; now you can just compute the variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But where am I supposed to use the given fact that: $Y∼Uni(0,1) $

You could do this.
$$\begin{align}f_X(x) ~&=~ \mathsf P({X=Y})~f_Y(x)+\mathsf P({X=1-Y})~f_Y(1-x)\\&=~\tfrac 12\cdot \mathbf 1_{x\in[0..1]}+\tfrac 12\cdot \mathbf 1_{1-x\in[0..1]}\\&=~\mathbf 1_{x\in[0..1]}\end{align}$$

Therefore the distribution for $X$ is known.

---

> I don't seem to use this anywhere which indicated I did something wrong.

No.  You were okay.  The expectation of $Y$ is cancelled so there is no need to use it here.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~&=~ \mathsf P({X=Y})~\mathsf E(Y)+\mathsf P({X=1-Y})~\mathsf E(1-Y)\\&=~\tfrac 12\mathsf E(Y)+\tfrac12(1-\mathsf E(Y))\\&=~\tfrac12\end{align}$$

However, this cancellation does not happen when you do likewise for the expectation of the square.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X^2) ~&=~ \mathsf P({X=Y})~\mathsf E(Y^2)+\mathsf P({X=1-Y})~\mathsf E((1-Y)^2)\\&=~\tfrac12~\mathsf E(Y^2)+\tfrac 12~\mathsf E(1-2Y+Y^2)\\&=~\tfrac 12-\mathsf E(Y)+\mathsf E(Y^2)\end{align}$$

So here you can use the fact: $Y\sim\mathcal U[0..1]$, and so find $\mathsf{Var}(X)$.

Comment: This is wrong... "() = (=) ()+(=1−) (1−)= 12()+12(1−())= 12" E(X) is all values x, X can get multiplied by P(X=x) Not E

Comment: From wikipedia: ${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [X]=\sum _{i=1}^{k}x_{i}\,p_{i}=x_{1}p_{1}+x_{2}p_{2}+\cdots +x_{k}p_{k}.}$

Comment: @Dan Graham Kemp is correct, he calculates $\mathbb E[X]$ by splitting into cases depending on which piece of the broken pencil you choose.

Comment: Again, the law I attached doesn't mention anything about $E[Y]$... The law says all values $X$ can get ie $x_i$ multiplied by probability of $X$ to be equal to $x_i$ @jlammy

Comment: Ie it should be E and E(1-y) not E[y-1] or E[y]

Comment: We don't use the "Law" you mention (the definition for expectation of a discrete random variable). 
Rather we use linearity of expectation:$$\def\E{\mathsf E}\E(X)=\E(X~\mathbf 1_{X=Y})+\E(X~\mathbf 1_{X=1-Y})\\\quad=\E(Y~\mathbf 1_{X=Y})+\E((1-Y)~\mathbf 1_{X=1-Y})$$...and the fact that which end we choose is independent of the break length.$$=\E(Y)~\E(\mathbf 1_{X=Y})+\E(1-Y)~\E(\mathbf 1_{X=1-Y})$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $p(x)$ is uniform, then $p(x)=1$.

$E[X]=\int_0^1 x p(x) dx$

$= \int_0^1 x dx $

$= \frac{1}{2}$.

$Var[X] = \int_0^1 (x -\mu)^2 p(x) dx $

$= \int_0^1 (x-\frac{1}{2})^2 dx $

$= \frac{1}{12}$

Comment: "Since $p(x)$ is uniform..."  Yes, it is, but the *why* needs to be explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:-

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y))$$

Then this is nothing but:-

$$\int_{0}^{1}(yP(X=y)+(1-y)P(X=1-y))\,dy=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}\,dy=\frac{1}{2}$$

The variance is also calculated in a similar way.

$$Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(Var(X|Y))+Var(\mathbb{E}(X|Y))$$

We have:-

$$Var(X|Y=y)=E((X-\frac{1}{2})^{2}|Y=y))=\frac{1}{2}(y-\frac{1}{2})^{2}+(1-y-\frac{1}{2})^{2}\frac{1}{2}=(y-\frac{1}{2})^{2}$$

So $\mathbb{E}(Var(X|Y))=\mathbb{E}((Y-\frac12)^2)=\int_{0}^{1}(y-\frac{1}{2})^{2}\,dy=\frac{1}{12}$.

And $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=\frac{1}{2}$

So $Var(\mathbb{E}(X|Y))=Var(\frac{1}{2})=0$ (As variance of a constant is $0$).

So you have your answer as $$Var(X)=\frac{1}{12}$$.

You can remember these two formulae . They can be really useful .

> $$Var(X)=\mathbb{E}(Var(X|Y))+Var(\mathbb{E}(X|Y))$$

And

> $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|Y))$$